# How to move a view alongside with the finger movements in android?

Tags: android

I have a simple setup in android studio, in acticity_main.xml I have an image view with the id "pong":

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pong"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="162dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"/>
```

I want to move this ImageView with my finger along the x-axis.
So basically I constantly need the X coordinate of a finger (if there is one) on the screen.
Then I need to change the x-coordinate of the ImageView accordingly (I know how to do this, the main question is how do I get the coordinate).

I have tried this with an OnTouchListener, but this only updated the x-coordinate whenever I clicked (when I let go), but I want the ImageView to move along with my finger constantly.
How do I do this?

Comment: Have you considered the `OnDragListener` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this way :

**Kotlin version**

```
var x : Double? = 0.0
var y : Double? = 0.0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    .......

    var yourImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pong)

    yourImage.setOnTouchListener{view , event->
        when (event.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                x = view.x.toDouble() - event.rawX
                y = view.y.toDouble() - event.rawY
                true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {

                // animate the image on x axis line only according to your finger movements
                yourImage.animate()
                        .x(event.rawX + x!!.toFloat())
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start()
                true
            }
            else -> {
                true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Java version**

```
float x ;
float y ;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    .........

    ImageView yourImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pong);

    yourImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : {
                    x = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    y = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE : {
                    yourImage.animate()
                            .x(event.getRawX() + x)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                    return true;
                }
                default: return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

- inside ACTION_DOWN event is where you can get the x and y coordinates
  when the user touch down the screen with his finger
- inside ACTION_MOVE event is where you can get the x and y every time the user moves his finger , then use the x and y coordinates to animate the property(x and y) of the image view in the way you want ,

Comment: and here where the java version

Comment: Thank you, what about, if I have to do this in a canvas, meaning wihout an event listener (I have a rect drawn on a canvas and want to move that rect accordingly), anyway of doing that? Preferably in Java.